# Rspec tests for checking uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Here is the rspec test to check the uniqueness of an email ( from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users.html#code-validates_uniqueness_of_email_test )

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end
  .
  .
  .
  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

As the author mentioned, I added

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  .
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
end
```

to my user model and the tests pass.

But @user hasn't yet been saved to the database(I can't find @user.save statement anywhere is the code.) so, user_with_same_email is already unique since there is no other user with the same email in the **database**. Then how does it work?

I created something similar in the console. user_with_same_email.valid? returns false (with error "has already been taken"), but user_with_same_email.save still works. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the [source code](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec-rails/1.3.2/classes/Spec/Rails/Matchers.html#M000018) for the `be_valid` matcher:

```
match do |actual|
  actual.valid?
end
```

As you can see, the matcher does not actually save the record, it just calls the method [`valid?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F) on the instance. `valid?` checks whether validations will pass or not and if not, sets error messages on the instance.

In the case above, you are first (successfully) saving a user with the same email (`user_with_same_email`), which works since no user with that email has actually been *saved* yet. Then you're checking for validation errors on another user instance (`@user`) which has the same email, and that obviously fails even though you have not actually saved the duplicate record.

Regarding what you get in the console, the problem is likely that `save` does not return an error even if it fails. Try using `save!` instead.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I thought it was the other way around. Now it all makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem.

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe User, 'validations' do
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
  it { should validate_format_of(:email).with_message(VALID_EMAIL_REGEX) }
end
```

Not positive about the last one, but it looks like it should work.

If you're using clearance, you can use the built-in `email_validator` functionality [PR here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/pull/266)

```
# app/models/user.rb
validates :email, presence: true, email: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont mess up the things. Break it into pieces and relax.

Find this below how you can test for checking uniquiness.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  it "when email address is already taken" do
    User.create(name: "example" , email: "example@gmail.com") 
    check_new_user = "example@gmail.com"
    result = User.find_by_email(check_new_user).present? ? false : true

    expect(result).to be(true)

   #notice: this test will fails because check_new_user is already in the 
            database. you can set emails according to yours.
  end
end
```